# SQS with low latency applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've been planning out an architecture that gets a request from a user, basically the user passes a piece of information to the system, the system performs some lookups, and updates a value in a database reflecting the new information. The application is latency sensitive, faster is better.

At first glance it seemed like SQS was a good fit. Basically, the request is picked up by lambda at edge, which performs some basic tasks and shoots a message off to SQS. The SQS message is picked up by a lambda, which processes it. Boom, good to go.

Here's what I think I might be missing. It sounds like if you're using long polling there's a minimum 1 second wait between when the message is sent and when its picked up. Is this correct? My assumption was that SQS could be used with latency-sensitive applications, but 1-2 seconds is a pretty big cost. If I'm understanding this right, what's the correct service to use here?

Comment: AWS [Kinesis Data Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-low-latency.html) is probably a more appropriate service if the SQS 1-2 seconds latency is a problem for you. Otherwise you might look at SNS since it is a "push" instead of "pull" service, or you might consider Amazon MQ or Amazon MSK.